# How to make reusable controllers in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on my first Asp.Net Core project, which is to support both a web client, and a Game client (written in Unity).

Now, I started with the default *Asp.Net Core Web Application* project template provided by Visual Studio 2015, including authentication for *Individual User Accounts*.

Most, if not all of the generated controllers are returning views, following this pattern in general:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //Do something smart
        return View();
    }
```

This method returns a *View* as you can see and all is good when requested by the web client.
But what if the Game is sending a request to the same method? 
In that case a JSON response is expected (not a View/html document), and my question is what is the recommended "pattern" for supporting this in Asp.Net Core?

Should I place the api returning JSON in separate controllers, hence duplicating some logic? It doesn't feel right to me...

Or should I check the request for an expected response format, and implement logic for returning different responses based on this?
I don't particularly like that approach either...

To me, it seems *Asp.Net Core* messes things up by providing UI formatted responses directly from the API, but it might be something I've missed here...

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the logic into a class to be called by the controller if you want separate controllers or actions for the Webpage and game.

This would be better and follow the single responsibility rule rather than one action returning two response types

Comment: I dont agree. Two or more response types from one action can avoid duplication of code logic (for example validating data)

Comment: At the expense of code complexity. Use routing to choose between MVC or web api actions, not if statements. Move non-UI logic into a service. Inject the service into the API and view-based controllers. As this answer suggests.

Comment: J Doe it wouldn't be duplication as you're moving the logic into a class.  The two controller actions have different 'responsibilities' as they return different types. This is one of the SOLID principles. It will keep the code much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

When the return type is IActionResult you can also return Json messages for example as `return Json(myReturnObject)`. You can add an `if` to return a JSON message and when it is false it will return the view.

You can add an if based on `X-Requested-With`:

```
if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
{
    return Json(myObject);
}
```

What I would recommend is to split the requests in different controller methods by response type and add the shared code/logic in a private method or to another class, probably you will use this elsewhere too. By doing this you will be able to do proper tests and won't get confused when it will return the view or a json message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding Hakany, but what should I base my If-statement on?
Some info in the request header?

Comment: When you send an ajax request it will send always `X-Requested-With` in  the header with as value `XMLHttpRequest`: HttpRequest.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest" or add this in the header of this request manually. You are also free to add a custom header key value, in this case you will also need to make changes to accept your custom header key.

Comment: Adding an if statement to *every* action method is going to result in poor code quality. Better to move the real logic into a service, and have a very thin action that returns views, and a separate one that returns JSON as a web api.

Comment: I agree with @ssmith, that is also mine recommendation mentioned in the last paragraph.